# How many words can be formed by taking 4 letters at a time from the letters of the word 'MORADABAD'?

Tags: permutations, problem-solving, combinations

What I tried was: (9P4)/3!*2! This gave me a wrong answer (since the answer is 626).

I'm unable to make use of the hint provided in my book: "make cases".

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: I agree it's a lot like the 'parallelogram' problem, but how would OP know that from a search. One good answer here, one there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the hint suggests, divide into cases, and count carefully.

Case 1: All $4$ letters distinct. There are $6$ different letters in our long word. We can arrange $4$ of them in a row in $(6)(5)(4)(3)$ ways. Alternately, e can choose the $4$ distinct letters in $\binom{6}{4}$ ways, and for each way arrange them in $4!$ ways, for a total of $\binom{6}{4}4!$.

Case 2: Two A's, the rest distinct. We can choose the places where the A's go in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. For each such choice, there are $(5)(4)$ ways to fill the remaining slots with two distinct letters chosen from the remaining $5$.

Case 2': Two D's, the rest distinct. Same analysis, answer as Case 2.

Case 3: Two A's, two D's. The places where the A's go can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.

Case 4: Three A's. We can choose where the A's go in $\binom{4}{3}$ ways, and the remaining slot can be filled in $5$ ways.

Add up.

Comment: Can you please tell me what my solution would give me? I'm unable to visualise the answer. :) thanks in advance.

Comment: Your $(9)(8)(7)(6)/(3!2!)$ is unconnected with solving the problem, Since the amount of "double counting" varies with the type of case you are dealing with. If you calculate the sum of my Cases, you will get $360+120+120+6+20$.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope the reasons for the various counts are clear.

Comment: When do we use the above stated formula? The one attempted in the question??